# How to identify train stations from (vague) codes?

Tags: geocoding, google-maps-api, railroad

I'm trying to identify and geocode several train stations based on location codes that were supplied to me. Most of them take the form "CCSSS" where "CC" appears to be an abbreviation for a country (such as "GB" or "BE" or "US") and "SSS" appears to be a station code.

However, some of the station codes don't match either an [IATA code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IATA-indexed_railway_stations), a [British station code](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/stations_destinations/48541.aspx), or an [Amtrak station code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Amtrak_stations). Some of them are only three letters long. Some of them contain an "@" symbol. The full list is uploaded [here](https://gist.github.com/gwerbin/b65bbe46b4711c03019b). Interestingly, Google was able to identify "GBQQS" as St. Pancras when I searched for "QQS train station great britain".

How can I reliably identify these stations?

If it's relevant, I'm planning to geocode the stations using the Google Maps API.

Comment: The easiest way would be to contact the author and ask them. Where does this data come from? If the provided data doesn't follow standard naming conventions for train stations, then helping would be difficult.

Comment: @Paul I just wasn't sure if there was some kind of train-station-identifying system I wasn't aware of. The data I'm working on was actually sent to me as part of a job interview process, and I already asked a big pile of questions so I'm hesitant to ask any more. If the answer is "there's no good answer," then I'll do without the geocoding in the project, and ask afterwards, if only to satisfy my curiosity (and have an excuse to start playing with GIS libraries).

Comment: Questions relating to geography and/or geographic trivia, with no clear GIS component, are off-topic here.

Comment: Geocoding usually implies there's an address associated with the data. Is there an address? And QQS seems like an airport code. Maybe that's a clue?

Comment: @Vince I asked about this in chat and got the okay to post it here.

Comment: You can always try against [this list](https://rocketrip.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204345378-What-rail-station-code-should-I-enter-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just going to expand on my answer above.

You can use the list to reference what exists and how it is structured [What Rail Station Code Should I Enter?](https://rocketrip.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204345378-What-rail-station-code-should-I-enter-) In there you will see examples of "GBQQS"

```
London St Pancras International (GBQQS) GB  GBQQS
```

as well as snippets of

```
DÃœSSELDORF FLUGHAFEN (DUS) (DE@DF) DE  DE@DF
```

give that it can be queried I can imagine you can compare that list to the [Google API for Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=en_US) and query "train_station"

> bus_station, train_station and transit_station indicate the location of a bus, train or public transit stop.

Try something like

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=train_station&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

for `[YOUR_API_KEY]` enter your [Google Developer API Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com)